# Bad or valid expression for gravitational redshift

Tags: general-relativity, redshift, gravitational-redshift

In my lecture of General Relativity, teacher takes the following metric :

$g_{\mu\nu}(x)=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}(x),~ {\rm with}\ h_{\mu\nu}\ll1$

**Qquestion 1)** I understand its first demonstration when he gets :

$\dfrac{\text{d}\tau}{\text{d}t}\simeq 1 + \dfrac{1}{2}h_{00}+h_{0i}\beta^{i}-\dfrac{1}{2}\beta^2$

with $V^{i}=\dfrac{\text{d}x^{i}}{\text{d}t}=\beta^{i}\,c$

But in the following, he's doing simplifications with negligible terms from the equation of geodesics :

$\dfrac{\text{d}v^{\mu}}{\text{d}\tau}+\Gamma_{\rho\sigma}^{\mu}\,v^{\rho}\,v^{\sigma}=0\quad\quad$ with $v^{\mu}=\dfrac{\text{d}x^{\mu}}{\text{d}\tau}$

and there, he seems to do a limited development by writing and obtaining :

$$v^{0}=c\,\dfrac{\text{d}t}{\text{d}\tau}\simeq\,c\bigg(1-\dfrac{1}{2}h_{00}+h_{0i}\,\beta^{i}+\dfrac{1}{2}\beta^2\bigg)$$

Shoudn't be rather a minus sign for $h_{0i}\,\beta^{i}$ term ? since :

$(1+x)^{-1}\simeq (1-x)$ when x is very small

That would give then :

$$v^{0}=c\,\dfrac{\text{d}t}{\text{d}\tau}\simeq\,c\bigg(1-\dfrac{1}{2}h_{00}-h_{0i}\,\beta^{i}+\dfrac{1}{2}\beta^2\bigg)$$

**Question 2)** Always in the following, he deduces the gravitational redshift considering :

$$h_{00} = -\dfrac{2GM}{r\,c^2}$$

and after, he writes, to compute the gravitational doppler between 2 sources located at $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$ and with $r_{2}-r_{1}=h<< R_{\text{Earth}}$

$\dfrac{\text{d}t_{1}}{\text{d}\tau_{1}}=\big(1- \dfrac{1}{2} h_{00}(r_{1})\big)$

$\dfrac{\text{d}t_{2}}{\text{d}\tau_{2}}=\big(1- \dfrac{1}{2} h_{00}(r_{2})\big)$

But there, he should use a $\simeq$ symbol considering the formula of **Question 1)** and since he does a limited development towards $h_{00}$, doesn't he ?

Then, this would give :

$\dfrac{\text{d}\tau_{1}}{\text{d}t_{1}}\simeq 1 - \dfrac{1}{2}h_{00}(r_{1})$

and

$\dfrac{\text{d}\tau_{2}}{\text{d}t_{2}}\simeq 1 - \dfrac{1}{2}h_{00}(r_{2})$

What I say is correct ?

**Question 3)** Finally, in the last part, he calculates this relative difference of frequency and find :

$$\dfrac{\Delta\nu}{\nu}=\dfrac{GM}{R\,c^2}\,\dfrac{h}{R}\quad\quad\,eq(1)$$

But I can't find the same expression : does the teacher has made approximations to find $eq(1)$ ?. This makes me problem since he uses an "equal" symbol in this expression.

Anyone could help me to get this final result ? I didn't see a clear demonstration on the web.

Hoping my questions are explicit, Regards

Comment: Can't anyone really gives me some tracks or suggestions ?

Comment: I am going to start soon a bounty to get help about these demonstrations, Regards